# How to put Qbittorrent webui port behind a https Apache2 server?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, proxy, mod-proxy

So basically, i have a apache2 server with https where i run some application

I am tring to using mod_proxy to proxy all traffic to url `example.com/qb` to `[::1]:qb-webui-port`.

So in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf`, i wrote:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset off
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</proxy>
ProxyPass /transmission http://[::1]:9091/transmission
ProxyPassReverse /transmission http://[::1]:9091/transmission
ProxyVia On

ProxyPass /qb http://[::1]:8112
ProxyPassReverse /qb http://[::1]:8112
```

The above is my similiar configuration for Transmission, i intended to do the same trick to Qbittorrent.
But it only returned plain html from `example.com/qb`.
In the firefox console i noticed that there were some request towards `example.com/css`, `example.com/script` etc.
This make me confused.

Can anyone provide some insights on this one?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the trailing slash on your addresses.
Here's my config file. I added a RewriteRule in case I enter the URL without the trailing slash. With these configs I haven't needed to modify anything else to get qb reverse proxy working.
I use the "/torrent/ subdir to access my qbittorrent webUI and it's listening on the 8080 port, so you should modify this in order to get your installation fully functional.

```
    # Para qbittorrent      
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule             ^/torrent$      "/torrent/$1" [R]
    ProxyPass               /torrent/       http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse        /torrent/       http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```